# missing file 'zplmr.cfg' / Couldn't find 'fpl.cfg'

Tags: packages, missing

MiKTeX couldn't find `zplmr.cfg` or `fpl.cfg`, which are used for some fonts.

Where could I get these files?

Comment: I doubt that you need them. Call in the MiKTeX console (as user) the task to refresh font map files.